# Cannot run chkdsk on SSD drive (WIN OS installed on it) due to I/O Device Error

Tags: ssd, chkdsk

Following another auto-update of the lovely Windows 10, I got my desktop run into a loop of 'Scanning and Repairing you Drive C' which restarts itself forever...

I managed to create a USB boot disc, in order to get to recovery mode.
In command prompt I type 'chkdsk C: /f /r' which gives the error:
Cannot perform due to I/O Device Error

My WIN 10 is installed on this SSD drive (C) - I do not think it is damaged as I can access the drive via Ubuntu.

Question - How can I somehow force the chkdsk to run on this SSD drive in order to fix the issue?

I know there are some methods that could run via Ubuntu but are dangerous for the drive.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, there are no tools that can actually fix NTFS partitions in Ubuntu. And I/O device error typically means the drive is indeed defective. If you still can see the files in an Ubuntu live session then do your backups and replace it.

Comment: And that this coincided with a Windows update is probably just that, a coincidence.

Comment: You *might* want to make a full-disk rescue clone to another drive (with e.g. `ddrescue` in a Linux live session), but not fix the filesystem "inplace".

Answer (score 0):

I hate to say it, but I think if your getting a device IO error from check disk (chkdisk) then Windows believes the drive is bad.   NOTE: Adding `/x` might help but I'm not sure.

If others come across this, below are my suggestions:

#### Boot into Safe Mode

First try to boot in Safe Mode.

**This used to be pressing F8 early in the Windows boot sequence.  I'm not positive how to do this in Windows 10.**  I tried to find links but the links showed how to boot into safe mode from a *working system* which doesn't help you.
See https://www.tomsguide.com/how-to/how-to-boot-into-windows-10-safe-mode

**NOTE2: I would first boot into my BIOS** so that I know I'm catching the boot sequence early.  Once I **know** that I'm pressing keys early enough, then you can try and time pressing the correct key to boot into Windows Safe mode.

#### Create a Windows PE bootable disk

If you can't get into Safe mode, then you'll need to create a Windows PE-based bootable USB or CD.  I haven't done this in years, but this is a link that looked useful:   https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/bootable-windows-pe-based-recovery-discs/

Summary of what it says in case the link disappears is:

- Lots of Windows rescue discs use a Linux environment. But there are also recovery discs that use the **Windows Preinstallation Environment (PE) instead**.
- Windows PE is a lightweight version of the Windows 10 operating system. You can use Windows PE to install, test, and repair a full installation of Windows 10. A Windows PE recovery disc will work with all Windows 10 versions: Home, Pro, Education, Enterprise, and so on.
- The base Windows PE version supports all Windows applications, drivers, networking tools, disk partitioning and management, Computer Management tools, Hyper-V, and much more. The Windows PE-based recovery discs step this functionality up, adding in tons of free and open-source tools you can use to recover, restore, and analyze your ailing Windows 10 installation.
- There are a few different options to download bootable CDs but because I haven't used them I don't want to endorse any specific one.

#### Run chkdisk /x/r

Once you are in a command line prompt, you can run this command:

```
chkdisk /x/r c:
```

This will force the C: drive to be repaired if it is repairable.
The `/x` option causes the drive to be unmounted if needed.  If it's your boot system, it will reboot and run the next time it boots (well if you were up and running sorry this won't work for you in your current state).

The `/r` repair option causes low level reads to be done on the entire drive and sectors to be relocated if there is room (on your disk) to new locations that are working.

See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chkdsk

> /r - Locates bad sectors and recovers readable information. The disk must be locked. /r includes the functionality of /f, with the additional analysis of physical disk errors.

> /x - Forces the volume to dismount first, if necessary. All open handles to the drive are invalidated. /x also includes the functionality of /f.

When I recently ran this, the following output was seen (edited to highlight issues)

```
chkdsk /x/r d:
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Volume label is D-DRIVE.

Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...
. . . 
Stage 2: Examining file name linkage ...
  255 reparse records processed.
Deleting index entry DSK-0~1.LCK in index $I30 of file 7C.
Deleting index entry M463.lck in index $I30 of file 47CA.
CHKDSK is scanning unindexed files for reconnect to their original directory.
Recovering orphaned file DSK-0~1.LCK (47CA) into directory file 7C.

Stage 3: Examining security descriptors ...

Stage 4: Looking for bad clusters in user file data ...
   NOTE: This is where you'll see problems or disk IO errors

Windows replaced bad clusters in file 1DD
of name \VIRTUA~1\V12-~1\DSK-0~1.VMD.
A disk read error occurredc0000185
The disk does not have enough space to replace bad clusters  <<< Your going to loose data
detected in file 2A01 of name \VIRTUA~1\V12-~1\DSK-0~2.VMD.
Windows replaced bad clusters in file 7675F
 Phase duration (User file recovery): 34.74 minutes.
An unspecified error occurred (75736e6a726e6c2e 500).
```

Even with this, it failed with an error so it didn't complete.  Kick it off again.
Realize that if you have CRC/Disk IO errors with your SSD, it's time to buy a new one and make a backup of your data.  Or at least this is my advice.

Answer (score 0):

**Primary reasons that cause I/O Device Error**

1. Outdated drivers
2. The hard drive is incompatible with the OS platform
3. Faulty CD/DVD writer and USB port
4. Loose USB or e SATA cord
5. Physically damaged hard drive

Most of the device I/O errors can be fixed by checking the loose connection, disk properties, etc. To fix these issues, there could be a variety of options. Before you continue to correct these errors you should first perform the following steps:

Restart your computer/Laptop.
Try to reaccess the drive/device.
If the problem remains the same, then try to access the device/drive data on another Computer/Laptop to confirm that the drive or device is not damaged.
The device input/output error is fixed and you no longer get the error message, you are finished. If the problem remains, then continue with the following solutions.

- **Check and Repair Device in Command Prompt**
  Press (Windows + X) both Keys together and select Command Prompt (Admin) from the menu list
  Click Yes to allow OS to launch the Command Prompt as Administrator.
  In Command Prompt window, type chkdsk G: /f /r /x. Here G is the drive letter; you can replace it with your drive letter.
  This option will check and repair disk errors on the external & internal hard drive to fix I/O device errors. And then you will no longer see the “The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error” message.
- **Change the drive transfer mode in IDE Channel Properties**
  OS cannot transfer data from drive to computer if the transfer mode is incorrect, you can change transfer mode by following steps.
- Press (Windows + X) both Keys together and select device manager from the menu list
  -Expand IDE ATA/ATAPI controllers. A subset will open, that lists the different IDE ATA/ATAPI channels.
- Right-click on the channel where the appropriate drive is connected, and then click properties. Typically, this channel is the Secondary IDE channel.
- Go to the advanced settings tab and select PIO Only in the transfer mode box for the device that represents the appropriate drive. Typically, this is device 0. Then, click ok and exit all windows.
- Test the drive and check if the error message has been removed.

Warning: Do not change the Primary IDE Channel, Device 0. Changing this transfer mode setting may cause the computer to operate incorrectly or not at all.
I hope you got your answer!!!